# Rails - best practice of handling restful update of a single attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I have **:users** resource with some typical attributes (first name, last name, email...) that user can update, but I also have some user attributes that typical user can not change himself or can change in a different way, for example **role** or **deactivated_at**.

A non-RESTful solution would be:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    put :change_role
    put :activate
  end
end
```

I am writing an API and my goal is to stick to REST constraints as much as possible. So my options as I see them are:

1. send everything to PATCH :update, and then add some more logic in that controller action
2. expose endpoints for those attributes and add new controllers for such cases, for example

```
resources :users do
  resource :role, only: :update
end
```

3. expose endpoints for those attributes and route them to a new action of existing controller

```
resources :users do
  resource :role, only: :update, to: 'users#update_role'
end
```

and still I am not sure what I would do with :activate?

Is there any other way, and what would be a recommended practice in this situation?

Comment: Seems kind of architecturally constricting to do this via routes. But I see the elegance you're looking for. I personally, would stick to keep this logic in the controllers. You would still need a controller action to fulfill the request whether or not there was a route written for it. /my_two_cents

Comment: @Trip, I am not sure that I understand what you mean. Keeping logic in the controller would mean reusing existing #update action for all single attribute updates, but then there would be no need for any new action, right?